# Writing Secure Server Applications with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, ssl

i have followed the tutorial "Writing Secure Server Applications with Qt" (https://blog.quickmediasolutions.com/2012/09/18/writing-secure-server-applications-with-qt.html) but i have the error:

[image: qt error]

**CSampleServer.h**

```
#ifndef CSAMPLESERVER_H
#define CSAMPLESERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>

class CSampleServer : public QTcpServer
{
public:
    CSampleServer();

private:
    void incomingConnection(int);

signals:
    void StatusMessage(QString);
};

#endif // CSAMPLESERVER_H
```

**CSampleServer.cpp**

```
#include "CSampleServer.h"
#include "CSecureSocket.h"

CSampleServer::CSampleServer()
{
}

void CSampleServer::incomingConnection(int handle)
{
    CSecureSocket * socket = new CSecureSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(StatusMessage(QString)), SIGNAL(StatusMessage(QString)));
    socket->Process(handle);
}
```

**CSecureSocket.h**

```
#ifndef CSECURESOCKET_H
#define CSECURESOCKET_H

#include <QSslSocket>

class CSecureSocket : public QSslSocket
{
public:
    CSecureSocket();
    void Process(int);


signals:
    void StatusMessage(QString);
};

#endif // CSECURESOCKET_H
```

**CSecureSocket.cpp**

```
#include "CSecureSocket.h"
#include <QHostAddress>

CSecureSocket::CSecureSocket()
{
}

void CSecureSocket::Process(int handle)
{
    /* Emit a message indicating the address of the client. */
    setSocketDescriptor(handle);
    emit StatusMessage(tr("Incoming connection from %1.").arg(peerAddress().toString()));

    /* Set the certificate and private key. */
    setLocalCertificate("server.crt");
    setPrivateKey("server.key.insecure");

    /* Start the server encryption process and wait for it to complete. */
    startServerEncryption();
    if(waitForEncrypted())
    {
        emit StatusMessage("Session with client is now encrypted.");

        /* Respond with a basic HTTP message. */
        write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
              "Content-type: text/plain\r\n"
              "Content-length: 12\r\n"
              "\r\n"
              "Hello World!");

        emit StatusMessage("Message sent to client. Closing connection.");
    }
    else
        emit StatusMessage(tr("An error occurred: %1.").arg(errorString()));

    /* Close the connection once the data is written. */
    disconnectFromHost();
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "CSampleServer.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void OnStart();
    void OnStatusMessage(QString);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    CSampleServer m_server;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(&m_server, SIGNAL(StatusMessage(QString)), SLOT(OnStatusMessage(QString)));
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(OnStart()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::OnStart()
{
    quint16 port = ui->spinBox->value();
    if(m_server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, port))
        OnStatusMessage(tr("Listening on port %1...").arg(port));
    else
        OnStatusMessage(tr("Unable to listen on port %1.").arg(port));
}

void MainWindow::OnStatusMessage(QString message)
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(message);
}
```

can you help me please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about showing your relevant code implicit?

Comment: i have updated the post with my code

Comment: Why don't you use QSSLSocket?

Comment: mmm good idea! yes. tnx!

Answer (score 4):

You can use SSL to create a secure server. Here is a Sample server using QSsLSocket:

```
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QMessageBox>

class server : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit server(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~server();

    QSslSocket server_socket;

public slots:


      void tcpReady();

      void encrypted();

      void sslError( QList<QSslError> errors );

      bool start_listen(int port_no);

protected:
    void incomingConnection( int descriptor );

};

server::server(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{

    server_socket.setProtocol(QSsl::SslV3);

    QByteArray key;
    QByteArray cert;

    QFile file_key("server.key");
    if(file_key.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        key = file_key.readAll();
        file_key.close();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << file_key.errorString();
    }

    QFile file_cert("server.crt");
    if(file_cert.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        cert = file_cert.readAll();
        file_cert.close();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << file_cert.errorString();
    }


    QSslKey ssl_key(key, QSsl::Rsa,QSsl::Pem,QSsl::PrivateKey,"server");

    QSslCertificate ssl_cert(cert);

    server_socket.addCaCertificate(ssl_cert);
    server_socket.setLocalCertificate(ssl_cert);
    server_socket.setPrivateKey(ssl_key);


    connect( &server_socket, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
            this, SLOT(sslError(QList<QSslError>)) );

    connect(&server_socket,SIGNAL(encrypted()),this,SLOT(encrypted()));

    server_socket.setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption, true );
}

server::~server()
{
    server_socket.disconnectFromHost();
    server_socket.waitForDisconnected();
}

void server::tcpReady()
{
    QByteArray array = server_socket.read( server_socket.bytesAvailable() );
    //...
}

void server::encrypted()
{
    connect( &server_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
             this, SLOT(tcpReady()) );
    emit connection_established();
}

void server::sslError(QList<QSslError> errors)
{
    QString erroStr="";
    foreach (const QSslError &e, errors)
        erroStr.append(e.errorString()).append("\n");

    QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error"),erroStr );

    server_socket.ignoreSslErrors();
}


bool server::start_listen(int port_no)
{
    if( !this->listen( QHostAddress::Any, port_no ) )
    {
        QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error!"), tr("Cannot listen to port %1").arg(port_no) );

    }
    else
        return true;
}

void server::incomingConnection(int descriptor)
{
    if(server_socket.state()!=QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState)
        return;
    if( !server_socket.setSocketDescriptor( descriptor ) )
    {
        QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error!"), tr("Socket error!") );
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        server_socket.startServerEncryption();
    }
}
```

You should generate a server.key and a server.crt file for your application.

Comment: nice solution @Nejat! i'll try now hoping that everything will be fine :D

Comment: https is a web protocol. I think we are talking about TCP connections. https also uses SSL (or TLS) i.e. HTTPS is HTTP-within-SSL. SSL (TLS) establishes a secured bidirectional tunnel for arbitrary binary data between two hosts.

Comment: yes...according to the guide it's possible...now the server run, but when i connect the browser (https://localhost:8080) error message: "QSslSocket::startServerEncryption: cannot start handshake on non-plain connection"

Answer (score 1):

This usage:

```
CSecureSocket * socket = new CSecureSocket(this);
```

is not compatible with this declaration/definition:

```
CSecureSocket();
```

Try:

```
CSecureSocket* socket = new CSecureSocket();
```

...

Comment: i have already made ​​this change...the current error now is:

D:\Users\x\Documents\QT Projects\SSLSocket\CSecureSocket.cpp:12: error: undefined reference to `CSecureSocket::StatusMessage(QString)'

Comment: Isn't your connect() is lacking another object parameter? It seems to me that you are connecting the signal `CSecureSocket::StatusMessage(QString)` to itself. Try `connect(socket, SIGNAL(StatusMessage(QString)), this, SIGNAL(StatusMessage(QString)))` or something like that...

Comment: i've already made this correction...nothing...:( I followed this article: https://quickmediasolutions.com/blog/13/writing-secure-server-applications-with-qt

Answer (score 0):

The problem is moc_* files were not generated for CSampleServer and CSecureSocket classes.

For that example to work, you need to:

1. add the Q_OBJECT macro to CSampleServer.h and CSecureSocket.h class definitions
2. clean the project
3. run **qmake** and make sure the moc_* files are there.
4. build the project again, the building issue should be gone at this point.

Answer (score 0):

1.void CSampleServer::incomingConnection(int handle)
argument should be of qintptr not in int.

2.connect(socket, SIGNAL(StatusMessage(QString)), SIGNAL(StatusMessage(QString))); statement is wrong where is receivers object

3.void CSecureSocket::Process(int handle) use qintptr

4.there are more errors to come read the documents properly